# How to add multiple rows with the same value and ID in one row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data like this:

```
|ID|partner_name|quantity|Price|Period |
|1 |partner 1   |     1  | 100 |01/2017|
|2 |partner 1   |     2  | 200 |01/2017|
|3 |partner 1   |     4  | 400 |01/2017|
|4 |partner 1   |     1  | 100 |02/2017|
```

I want the data to be like this:

```
|ID|partner_name|quantity|Price|Period |
|1 |partner 1   |     7  | 700 |01/2017|
|2 |partner 1   |     1  | 100 |02/2017|
```

How can i create that with sql?

thanks,

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should group your query:

```
SELECT partner_name, SUM(quantity), SUM(price), period FROM your_table
GROUP BY partner_name, period;
```

This will merge rows with same `partner_name` and `period` together.